# client without JRE can install any browser?

Tags: java, browser

I want to know which browser dosent require JRE to be installed.

I am asking this question because i want to know how user input on a webpage hits web server port and over the wire how information is structured as request.

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A browser uses a JRE for running Java applets on web pages, which are uncommon.  Ordinary requests to a server, such as clicking links or submitting input from a form, have nothing to do with Java or the JRE.

If you want to learn about how HTTP requests are structured, [RFC 2616](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616.html) is the standard.

Comment: Hi Wyzard, so client input from browser is transfered over TCP in header and body. client input can be in header or in body of TCP packet. If i am right so far i need to know what happens when this TCP packet hits web server?

Comment: @vishal, that depends entirely on what software is running on the server.  If it's something like Apache configured to serve static files, the URL path will be used to decide what file to send back.  If it's a PHP page, the URL path will be used to find a `.php` file and run it.  Those are a few common examples, but the server *could* be programmed to do *anything*.

Comment: @vishal, regardless of exactly what the server does, in the end it'll send a response back to the browser.  The response consists of a status code (such as 200 OK or 404 Not Found), some HTTP headers, and a body (typically an HTML page).

Comment: This question came in my mind due to another question --> why HttpServlet implements Serializable Interface.

Answer (score 0):

None of the web browsers that matter require a JRE, as Windows, Mac OS, and Linux all ship with no JRE installed.